# Stats problem, stacking cards

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

If I have n cards and n stacks of cards, how many ways can I split the cards between the stacks if the order of the cards in the stack is significant but the order of the stacks is insignificant and stacks are allowed to be empty. **And is there an algorithm to find them**.

So for example, with two cards (a, b) and two stacks the possible arrangements are:
[ab][],[ba][], [a][b]. ([b][a] is equivalent to [a][b])

this might seem like a silly problem but I am very much stuck and very much desperate

Comment: Interesting question, Please [edit] the question to post the counts for $n = 3$ and $4$. If the order of the stacks mattered you could count the ways to split each possible permutation. Perhaps start with that problem.

Comment: @EthanBolker not sure what you mean, the truth is what I really need is an algorithm to generate all the arrangements

Comment: Please write down your attempt, so that it was clear what you mean by "algorithm".

Answer (score 3):

Let us break up your problem into some smaller sub-problems. More specifically, how many ways are there two place $n$ distinct cards in $n$ identical stacks, where the number of nonempty stacks is exactly $m$ ($1\le m\le n$)? The answer is
$$
\frac{n!}{m!}\binom{n-1}{m-1}
$$
First, you arrange all $n$ cards into a single stack in $n!$ ways. There are $n-1$ places that are between two adjacent cards; you then select $m-1$ of these places, and place a divider in the chosen places, in $\binom{n-1}{m-1}$ ways. This divides the entire stack into $m$ nonempty sections, representing the $m$ stacks. Finally, we divide by $m!$, since the order of the stacks does not matter. Note that each of the $m!$ permutations of the sub-stacks is different, because the sub-stacks are nonempty.

Summing over all $m$, the answer to your question is
$$
\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{n!}{m!}\binom{n-1}{m-1} 
$$
For example, when $n=3$, the result is
$$
3!\left(\binom20+\frac12\binom21+\frac16\binom22\right)=13,
$$
and indeed there are $13$ arrangments.

Comment: thank you so much, I just need to find them all now